# Why are characters invisible no matter what cartridge I put in my SNES?

Tags: technical-issues, snes

I have a Super Nintendo with several game cartridges. When you place the game in, it will load fine, all sound and pictures, until the actual time to play. The background is visible, but no Aladdin, no Mowgli, or no Simba will appear so you can play. I can hear these characters, and if you use the joystick, the background will move, and you can hear the characters grunting as they are attacked until they die. How can I get these to work?

Comment: Does your problem pertain to multiple games, or just one specific game? You speak of `several game cartridges`, but the characters you listed seem to originate from a single Disney game. Please don't assume that people automatically know what you're talking about; be as descriptive as you can, when asking your question. You are more likely to get answers, the more people know what you want.

Comment: Sorry. It is multiple games. We tried about five different ones and they are all the same.

Comment: Do you or any one you know have a different system you could try. It seems like you are having issues getting all of the information from the cartridge to your system. Feels like such an issue would just make the loading not work at all. Something you might want to check on, would be to shine a light down into the system and make sure that all the pins look like they are free from any obstruction. Just a guess, but what if all the games have a specific pin that communicates what the players sprite is supposed to look like? And your system has an issue with just that ONE pin.